# Ether exchange for mobile app users

Tags: dapp-development, mobile-wallet, exchange-api

I am working on an ethereum powered mobile app and want to know the best to way to integrate an exchange for new users who do not have an existing accounts to purchase ether?

What's the best way for new users of my app to create accounts on an exchane, like Coinbase for example, and then purchase ether and send it to the mobile app wallet? Can it be done programmatically with the app via an API?

Answer (score 1):

If you only need an Ethereum wallet for the user, It is better to generate that in the browser and give the file to the user. This is the best practice as user will be responsible for their own keys. You can make the import/export options such as one used in MyEtherWallet make it more user friendly.

Such method is preferred to usage of APIs to generate wallets and kept locally. Then you can use the exchange API to purchase coins to the user's address.

You can check on example of this implementation here: [Code](https://github.com/go-faast/faast-portfolio), [Website](https://faa.st/portfolio#/)

Comment: Thanks that is very useful for the wallet side of the app.  We will need a way to buy ether to fund the wallet as well.  Any suggestions there?

Comment: @RLin It depends on your jurisdiction, accepted payment methods and limits. Not sure what are these details for you.

Comment: We are looking at about $100-$500 at a time weekly or monthly.  Jurisdiction would be New Jersey / New York

Comment: @RLin In NY due to Bitlicense, it was really challenging to offer cryptocurrency services. Not sure if it has changed since. Your best option is to try to partner with one service provider, such as coinbase or maybe bitaccess.co . Still you may be able to find better local crypto brokerages to work with. But anyways try to use in app/browser wallet generations for user so they would hold their own keys, rather than making wallets on 3rd party websites. Good luck